# Angular 8. Testing. suma > should be called Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for suma()

Tags: angular, typescript

Estaba desarrollando una App en Angular 8 con TypeScript como lenguaje de Script, y me ha surgido el siguiente error testeando uno de los componentes.

```
EscaparateTerminalesComponent > suma > should be called
Error: <spyOn> : could not find an object to spy upon for suma()
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

El archivo spec.ts es el siguiente:

```
describe('EscaparateTerminalesComponent', () => {
  let component: EscaparateTerminalesComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<EscaparateTerminalesComponent>;
  beforeEach(async(() => {
    
    ...
    const declaration     
    ...

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
      declarations: [EscaparateTerminalesComponent],
      imports: [HttpClientModule, HttpClientTestingModule, LoggerTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: PageDefaultValueControlService,
          useFactory: pageDefaultValueControlServiceStub
        },
        { provide: ChangeDetectorRef, useFactory: changeDetectorRefStub },
        { provide: DetallesMovilService, useFactory: detallesMovilServiceStub },
        { provide: NgbModal, useFactory: ngbModalStub },
        {
          provide: DatosCintillosService,
          useFactory: datosCintillosServiceStub
        },
        {
          provide: DetallesMovilService, useFactory: detallesMovilServiceStub
        },
        { provide: CurrentDataService, useFactory: currentDataServiceStub },
        { provide: DatosCintillosService, useFactory: datosCintillosServiceStub },
        { provide: ActivatedRoute, useFactory: activatedRouteStub },
        { provide: Router, useFactory: routerStub },
     
        { provide: OrangeApi, useFactory: orangeApiStub }
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  describe('suma', () => {
    it('should be called', () => {
      const a = '';
      const b = '';
      const spy = spyOn(component, 'suma').and.callThrough();
      component.suma(a, b);
      expect(component.suma).toBeTruthy();
      expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
```

Y el código del componente como tal es el siguiente:

```
  suma(a, b) {
    return (Number(a) + Number(b)).toFixed(2);
  }
```

Espero puedan ayudar si saben por donde van los tiros,  si es así, muchas gracias de ante mano!

Comment: Creo que has inicializado todo el TestBed pero luego te has olvidado de inicializar la variable `component`

Answer (score 1):

Te falta inicializar el propio componente y asignarlo a la variable `component`:

```
component = TestBed.createComponent(EscaparateTerminalesComponent);
```

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, y donde debería añadirlo?? Despues del describe, pero antes del it, verdad?